# Does layoutIfNeeded will update the layout of deep child's layout

Tags: ios

For example, i got view hierarchy like this:

[image]

And my question is: If i call `layoutIfNeeded` of `UIStackView`, the `VideoController` layout will be updated?

I seems that the `VideoController` layout will only updated if `layoutIfNeeded` of `UIView` is called. But apple's document says:

[image]

Comment: That doc says that it lays out the "subtree starting at the root”. So it’s the whole “subtree” (including its children).

Comment: @Rob So the child of child should be layouted. But from my test, it doesn't.

Comment: Try `setNeedsLayout()`. Perhaps you can give us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the actual problem you’re trying to solve...